# How to change view of a list in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a list with a Query

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text1 | text2 | text3 |

how to arrange the list otherwise? Like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| a | text1 |
| b | text2 |
| c | text3 |

I tried the STRING_SPLIT Function in T-SQL, but i does not work with a Subquery inside like

```
Select value FROM String_Splitt ((Select * FROM TABLE1), ',')
```

Comment: You need to use a cross join to turn one row into three rows. Then use `case` or `iif` to pick out the right value for each row. Do you always have only three columns?

Comment: no there are ten columns

Comment: Ok as long as it’s fixed.

Comment: I need to rearannge the columns and the text inside. But how to do. Maybe with a pivot function?

Comment: There are no lists in SQL. `STRING_SPLIT` is uses to split strings and return a table with the values. What you showed is the original result set *un*pivoted so that columns become rows

Comment: Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example

Comment: Yes, its not a list, its a table with columns and one row

Answer (score 0):

We can try to use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES` to make unpivot

```
SELECT v.*
FROM T CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
 ('a',a),
 ('b',b),
 ('c',c)
) v (name,val)
```

if you have more than three columns we can just put them after `VALUES`

```
SELECT v.*
FROM T CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
 ('a',a),
 ('b',b),
 ('c',c),
 -- more columns 
) v (name,val)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ad155bfc8b7fcb9e72c76568ebf53951)

Comment: its look solid, but I is possible to put a subquery into the VALUES

Comment: @PeterXO No even unpivot or pivot, we need to use column name in them unless dynamic SQL, but we might not create too many columns in one table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is completely generic regardless of the number of columns in a table.

Converting a db table into key-value pairs.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ColA VARCHAR(10), ColB CHAR(3), ColC INT);
INSERT INTO   @tbl (ColA, ColB, ColC) VALUES
('Abc', 'Bcd', 123),
('Cde', 'Def', 234);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SELECT p.ID --p.* , c
    , x.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(20)') as [col_name]
    , x.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [col_value]
FROM @tbl AS p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @tbl AS c WHERE p.ID = c.ID
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY t1.c.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID | col_name | col_value |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | ID       | 1         |
|  1 | ColA     | Abc       |
|  1 | ColB     | Bcd       |
|  1 | ColC     | 123       |
|  2 | ID       | 2         |
|  2 | ColA     | Cde       |
|  2 | ColB     | Def       |
|  2 | ColC     | 234       |
+----+----------+-----------+
```